# How to pass the model attribute object values one controller to another controller by rediect url

Tags: java, spring

Using the redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("object",objectvalue);

Like this way it is successfully redirecting the object value to the next controller, but when we returned the view in the next controller it display the result in html page in browser. Then the problem starts when we refresh or reload the page then values disappears.

My code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addRoom", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveRoom(Room room,
        ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes ra) {
    amenitiesService.saveRoom(room);
    Floor floor = amenitiesService.getFloorInfo(room.getFloorId());
    String floorName = floor.getFloorName();
    ra.addFlashAttribute(room);
    ra.addFlashAttribute("floorName", floorName);
    ra.addFlashAttribute("message","Room information is saved successfully.");
    return "redirect:/redirectedUrl";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/redirectedUrl")
public String redirecturl(Room room, ModelMap model) {
return ADMIN_VIEW + SAVE_ROOM;
}
```

please any one suggest me how to redirect the object values to next controller with permanent not temporary visible like flash attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this it may be work

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirectedUrl")
public String redirecturl(Room room, ModelMap model, RedirectAttributes re) {
String name=(String)re.getFlashAttributes("floorName");
return ADMIN_VIEW + SAVE_ROOM;
}
```

Comment: with out using RedirectAttributes in public String redirecturl(Room room, ModelMap model) mehod also working fine. after redirection of the view when we refresh the browser the values are become null i.e main problem by using the RedirectAttributes .